# Can't create SDL2 texture using SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV12 pixel format

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL 2.0.5 and Windows 10 to create a window and display a texture.

Everything works fine when the texture has been initialized with SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YV12 pixel format, but when I set the format to SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV12, SDL_CreateTexture function returns null.

Here's the code:

```
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    width,
    height,
    SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP
);

SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window , -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);

SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(
    renderer,
    SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV12,
    SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
    width,
    height
);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure your hardware/driver supports `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV12`?

Comment: I don't know, but setting SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE instead of SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED give me the same result.

Comment: Software renderer [doesn't support](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ba1da2658d76/src/render/software/SDL_render_sw.c#l84) this format. In fact, only GL and GLES2 renderers do.

Comment: Allright. So, in order to use a NV12 texture in SDL2, you must get the appropriate hardware/driver to make it work?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see it is only supported on GL renderer with shaders support available. If you're on windows, SDL defaults to d3d renderer (which can be changed by setting appropriate hint).

Comment: Yes you are totally right! Seems to work perfectly using  SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl"); and SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to keltar's comment, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV12 requires an hardware acceleration.

One solution is to use the OpenGL renderer which supports NV12 pixel format.

So, setting hint as follow:
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl"); and setting SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED flag to SDL_CreateRenderer function does the trick.